# Combine two inner join queries into one procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, inner-join

```
        SELECT TOP 15
      us.MxitId AS TransactionCreatedBy, COUNT(t.CreatedBy) Total
FROM [User] us
INNER JOIN [Transaction] t ON t.CreatedBy = us.UserId
Where ChildGender = 'Male'
GROUP BY us.MxitId, t.ChildGender 
ORDER BY 2 desc





SELECT TOP 15
      us.MxitId AS TransactionCreatedBy, COUNT(t.CreatedBy) Total
FROM [User] us
INNER JOIN [Transaction] t ON t.CreatedBy = us.UserId
Where ChildGender = 'Female'
GROUP BY us.MxitId, t.ChildGender 
ORDER BY 2 desc
```

I am trying to combine the above two procedures into one.

**Please can anyone help me i am getting repeat values for the  `us.MxitId` column.**

```
 Select   us.MxitId AS TransactionCreatedBy,
(SELECT TOP 15
         COUNT(t.CreatedBy) TotalMale where ChildGender = 'Male') ,

          ( Select top 15 COUNT(t.CreatedBy) TotalFemale where ChildGender = 'Female')


    FROM [User] us
    INNER JOIN [Transaction] t ON t.CreatedBy = us.UserId

    GROUP BY us.MxitId, t.ChildGender 
    ORDER BY 2 desc
```

Comment: How do you want to combine them?  The top 15 Users for boys could be completely different than the top 15 Users for girls. Or, they could be the same list, but in different order.  Show us what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Hi the users are same for both cases i want to say 0 if the user hasnt recorded any female data or vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work to get the gender count without having duplicate MxitId's.

```
SELECT TOP 15
      us.MxitId AS TransactionCreatedBy
, COUNT(t.CreatedBy) AS Total
, SUM(CASE WHEN ChildGender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FemaleCount
, SUM(CASE WHEN ChildGender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MaleCount
FROM [User] us
INNER JOIN [Transaction] t ON t.CreatedBy = us.UserId
GROUP BY us.MxitId
ORDER BY 2 desc
```

Comment: It says in this comment box before typing: Please avoid comments like +1 and thanks.. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT TOP 15
      us.MxitId AS TransactionCreatedBy, 
    sum(case when ChildGender = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end) TotalMale
      ,sum(case when ChildGender = 'feMale' then 1 else 0 end) TotalFeMale
FROM [User] us
INNER JOIN [Transaction] t ON t.CreatedBy = us.UserId

GROUP BY us.MxitId, t.ChildGender
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'TotalMale'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'TotalFeMale'.

Comment: put end inside bracket

Comment: hi the data is still repeating

Comment: i don't know the table structure their relation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
SELECT TransactionCreatedBy, ChildGender, Total
FROM (SELECT us.MxitId as TransactionCreatedBy, t.ChildGender, COUNT(t.CreatedBy) as Total,
             row_number() over (partition by t.ChildGender order by COUNT(t.CreatedBy) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM [User] us INNER JOIN
           [Transaction] t
           ON t.CreatedBy = us.UserId
      GROUP BY us.MxitId, t.ChildGender 
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 15
ORDER BY Total desc;
```

I also added gender to the `select` list so you can see which rows come from which table.

If you want to put both counts in the same table and then take the top 15 by some measure:

```
      SELECT us.MxitId as TransactionCreatedBy, COUNT(t.CreatedBy) as Total,
             sum(case when t.ChildGender = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalMales,
             sum(case when t.ChildGender = 'Female' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalFemales
      FROM [User] us INNER JOIN
           [Transaction] t
           ON t.CreatedBy = us.UserId
      GROUP BY us.MxitId, t.ChildGender 
      ORDER BY COUNT(t.CreatedBy) desc
      LIMIT 15;
```

Answer (score 0):

Write as:

```
select top 15 us.MxitId AS TransactionCreatedBy,
        count(case ChildGender when 'Male' then 1 else null end) as MaleCount,
        count(case ChildGender when 'Female' then 1 else null end) as FemaleCount
from [User] us
INNER JOIN [Transaction] t ON t.CreatedBy = us.UserId
GROUP BY us.MxitId
```